# UITableView Header not showing in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have `UITableView` with `header` and on my device the header is showing just fine but when I run the app on the simulator the header disappears..

What might be the cause of it?

Comment: Try to enlarge size of simulator by pressing cmd+(1, 2 ,3 ,4)

Comment: still the same, no header :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you added header height method? like - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: yes of course, as i mention above the table works fine on the device but on the simulator it doesn't appear